# Can one use "much" as in the statement "I am looking forward to seeing you much"?

Tags: word-usage

It would seem natural (to me) to say "I am very much looking forward to seeing you." Could you then get rid of the 'very' and put 'much' at the end to get "I am looking forward to seeing you much"? .. which somehow sounds on the border of odd and ok. What do you think?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't sound so bad if you say 'very much', but   it is still awkward and best avoided. However it is not nearly as bad as saying 'looking forward to seeing you muchly'. If you ever hear 'muchly' run for the exits!

Comment: Muchly. Never heard it before. It's plain sweet! :)

Comment: You could use "a lot" instead of much

Comment: "I am very much looking forward to seeing you." does not sound odd at all. It's how I say it anyways

Answer (score 3):

*Much* is just one of those words that needs *very* in a sentence like the one you quoted, otherwise it just doesn't sound right. Oddly enough, it's fine when expressed as a negative.

*I would very much like to work with him.*

*I wouldn't much like to work with him.*

Answer (score 1):

your first phrase is quite common, the second is not used and would sould odd

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't get rid of the 'very', but you could move it with 'much' to read "I am looking forward to seeing you very much".

Comment: That could sound a bit creepy—I'm not entirely sure I'd like to be _seen very much_, just as a general precaution…